# Particle and antiparticle operators in position space

Tags: operators, fourier-transform, dirac-equation, antimatter, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I need to study the two-point correlation functions of the creation/annihilation operators of particle/antiparticle, $\hat{a}^{(\dagger)}$ and $\hat{b}^{(\dagger)}$, in position space. It is customary to expand the field $\hat{\psi}$ as (for simplicity I assume the (1+1)-dimensional case)
$$\hat\psi(x)=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\left(\hat{a}_ku_k(t)e^{ikx}+\hat{b}_k^\dagger v_k(t)e^{-ikx}\right)=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\left(\hat{a}_ku_k(t)+\hat{b}_{-k}^\dagger v_{-k}(t)\right)e^{ikx},$$

where $u_k(t)$ and $v_{-k}(t)$ are mode functions satisfying the Dirac equation in momentum space (in flat spacetimes these are just possitive/negative frequency plane waves). My first guess was that, in position space, we would simply have
$$\hat{a}(x)=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi}\hat{a}_ke^{ikx},\\\hat{b}^\dagger(x)=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\hat{b}_{-k}^\dagger e^{ikx}.$$

But then, if I use the inverse transformation and insert it in the original expansion of the field, I get
$$
\hat{\psi}=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\left[u_k(t)\int dy\;\hat{a}(y)e^{-ik(y-x)}+v_{-k}(t)\int dz\;\hat{b}^\dagger(z)e^{-ik(z-x)}\right].
$$

It almost look like two Dirac deltas would appear due to the exponential, but integration in $k$ includes also the mode functions $u_k$ and $v_{-k}$, so I'm not able to recover the original expression.

Because of this, I think that my original Fourier transforms of $\hat{a}_k$ and $\hat{b}_{-k}$ must be wrong, but I cannot come up with a correct transformation. How would then one obtain those operators in position space?

Edit: as an example, the type of correlators that I would like to calculate are $\langle\hat{a}^\dagger(x)\hat{a}(y)\rangle$, $\langle\hat{b}^\dagger(x)\hat{b}(y)\rangle$,
$\langle\hat{b}^\dagger(x)\hat{a}(y)\rangle$…

Comment: Multiplication in momentum space amounts to convolution in coordinate space, no?

Comment: Review [Freedman,  Johnson, & Latorre  (1992).  *Nuclear Physics* **B371** 353-414](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(92)90240-C).

Comment: I’ve taken a look at that review but, for the case of fermions, it seems that it only mentions correlators constructed by using $\hat{\psi}$, but what I need is constructing operators constructed with particle/antiparticle operators only, eg. $\langle\hat{a}^\dagger(x)\hat{a}(y)\rangle$. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Free fields in coordinate space do not represent decoupled normal modes, as per their construction! See first comment...

Comment: From your comment I understand that $\hat{\psi}$ cannot be written in terms of “spatial” creation/annihilation operators in a decoupled expression, but rather as an expression involving convolutions. But I don’t quite understand if the Fourier transformed operators that I wrote in the original question are well-defined as I wrote them, or if rather the transformation between $\hat{a}_k$ and $\hat{a}(x)$ must follow another expression, perhaps involving the specific mode functions used for the expansion of the field in momentum space.

Comment: ? The way you wrote them, the coordinate space oscillators have simple commutation relations; if you modify them, you get messier, modified commutation relations. Your quantization of classical FT text should be fully explaining the [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#One-dimensional_lattice).